# How to create MySQL schema using URL in spring boot?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have seen that in the H2 database there is a way to create schema at the time of execution of the program (As the following way).

Inside spring boot application.properties file,

```
URL: jdbc:h2:file:../data/user_data?DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS user_data
```

Is there any way to configure the same thing in MySQL?

Sorry but don't expect answer,

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I want it in URL part only.

Comment: I don't think such an option exists for MySQL, but what is wrong with controlling this behavior from Spring?

Comment: Thanks, @TimBiegeleisen for the answer. Let's wait for other's suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use "createDatabaseIfNotExist" option in mysql?

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

[source](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create database which does not exists use below in database in your configuration file.

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true